# Running two aws cli commands both at once

Tags: aws-cli

I would like to run the following:

```
aws ram get-resource-share-invitations
aws ram accept-resource-share-invitation --resource-share-invitation-arn <value from first query>
```

both in one line taking the output from the first query and using it in second.

Is there a way to do this? I want to use the above script inside terraform null_resource. As we cannot get output from null_resource. I was thinking if I combine both queries into one it will resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can chain AWS cli commands together by using `xargs`

CAVEATS:  I don't use AWS RAM so I'm unable to provide a specific example but this should get you on the right road.  I also have not tested this in Terraform.

This code describes all classic ELB resources and sends the `load-balancer-name` of each to the `describe-load-balancer-attributes` which requires the `load-balancer-name`

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName]' --output text | xargs -I {} aws elb describe-load-balancer-attributes --load-balancer-name {}
```

What I think will work but I have no way to test is:

```
aws ram get-resource-share-associations --association-type <blah> --query 'resourceShareAssociations[*].[resourceShareArn]' --output text |xargs -I {} aws ram accept-resource-share-invitation --resource-share-invitation-arn {}
```